# Google API to send multiple URLs for indexing

Tags: google-api

I'm using the google API for send the URL for indexing.
`Url: https://indexing.googleapis.com/v3/urlNotifications:publish`

is google contain any API for send the multiple URL for indexing in one request.

I've try the google doc to find it but can't find any of it.
`Doc: https://developers.google.com/search/apis/indexing-api/v3/using-api#batching`

Comment: What do you mean by "the multiple URL"?